# division in php

Tags: php

```
 $voltage = '0.4000';
                    $newValue = str_replace('0.','',$voltage);
                    echo 'newvalue'.$newValue;
                    $newValue = $voltage/0.0125;
                    echo 'newvalue'.$newValue;
```

when i do like this i get 32 after division where as i should get 320000. any problem in wht i am doing ?

Comment: why you you not just multiply by 1000 instead of doing a string replace? keep everything casted as floats until the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If youre doing number opertations then use numeric functions and varibles not strings...

```
$voltage = (float) '0.4000'; //cast as a float, assuming this comes from user input as string
$newValue = $volatge*1000;
echo 'newvalue'.$newValue;

$newValue = $newValue/0.0125;
echo 'newvalue'.$newValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

You said `$newValue = $voltage/0.0125`. You probably meant to say `$newValue = $newValue/0.0125`

You never changed `$voltage` so it's still 0.4000, not 4000.

Answer (score 1):

Err... I'm sure it's typo, but I think you meant

```
$newValue = $newValue / 0.0125
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $newValue =  $newValue/0.0125;
```